# В сборку не попадают необходимые references. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, dll, рефлексия, assembly

Добрый день!

Имеется класс:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace namespace1
{
    public class AClass
    {
        public void Run(string Code)
        {
            // Формируем зависимости
            Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            ScriptOptions options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(assemblies);

            // Запускаем скрипт
             var result = CSharpScript.RunAsync(Code, options);
        }
    }
}
```

Всё просто: получаю сборки текущего домена -> копирую их в настройки скрипта -> выполняю скрипт.
Код, который пытаюсь передать в процедуру Run:

```
string code = @"using Excel = NetOffice.ExcelApi; "
                   + @"Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application(); ";
```

Как Вы заметили, в передаваемом коде я использую using. Который должен ссылаться на соотв. dll (NetOffice.ExcelApi).
В проекте данная ссылка присутствует: 
Свойства

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К сути: 
когда я получаю AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(), то там соответственно нет сборки NetOffice. Как я понял, это связано с тем, что компилятор умный и не загружает те сборки, которые в коде не используются явно. Всё логично (это подтвердилось, когда я в код метода Run добавил строку:

```
NetOffice.ExcelApi.Application SomeVar = new NetOffice.ExcelApi.Application();
```

После, я решил, что буду принудительно подгружать dll в домен. Но выяснил, что при сборке проекта, эта dll не попадает в файлы сборки, хотя на них стоит свойство "Копировать локально".

В связи с этим несколько

1) Возможно ли, принудительно заставить сборщик копировать неиспользуемые явно ссылки(dll) в релизную папку.

2) Можно ли, получить получить список всех Assemblies(может просто список имён) в коде, включая те, что не используются явно? (приложение не ASP.NET)

**P.S.**
В C# совершенный новичок. 100% где-то пока недопонимаю некоторые вещи. Прошу понять и простить :) 
Буду благодарен, если посоветуете хорошие источники для прокачки скила в C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если вы используете сборку в коде (не через `Assembly.Load`, а через добавленную ссылку), то она **должна** скопироваться в выходной каталог.
2. Есть не вполне надёжный путь

   ```
   Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
   ```

   Он ненадёжен потому, что компилятор имеет полное право сборку, которая не используется в проекте, и не включать в список referenced assemblies.

   Правильный путь — указывать список нужных сборок *явно*, а не пытаться где-то его раздобыть окольными путями.

---

Да, кроме того, выбранный вами путь (динамически сгенерировать скрипт и выполнить его через scripting API) представляется немного странным. Подозреваю, что того же результата можно достигнуть и проще, прямо вызывая нужное API.

Comment: 1) я собираю проект в visual studio. Т.е. при этом методе, у меня в любом случае все указанные мной в references(через nuget) ссылки должны попасть в выходной каталог, правильно?

Comment: @Serovkir: Они у вас есть в зависимостях проекта? А то может вы добавили, а потом удалили.

Comment: @Serovkir: Ваш скриншот в вопросе отображает актуальное положение вещей?

Comment: 1) я собираю проект в visual studio. Т.е. при этом методе, у 2) этот вариант как раз и не подходит, т. к. Компилятор не добавляет туда неиспользуемые сборки. /// По архитектуре: мне необходимо сделать что-то, вроде динамического компилятора. Я передаю туда код, он выполняется, при этом используя те библиотеки, которые я указал ref. Ваши сомнения понимаю, но для этого есть причины.

Comment: Отражает, на текущий момент так и есть.

Comment: @Serovkir: Окей, сначала по первой части. У вас реально сборка NetOffice не попадает в выходной каталог, несмотря на то, что включена в проект как ссылка и в свойствах есть CopyLocal = true? Если так, этого не должно быть. Перепроверьте, может быть, вы смотрите в каталог Release, а компилируете Debug. Попробуйте Rebuild. CopyLocal = true **должно** работать.

Comment: 1) Выяснил. Сборка NetOffice.dll попадает в каталог Debug, всё нормально. Не попадало в другое место: у меня есть проект с классом, который я описал в вопросе. Я делаю сборку как dll. На этом этапе всё ОК. Далее, я делаю ещё один проект, зависимый от вышеуказанной сборки. Вызываю метод Run и передаю туда код. Вылетает ошибка, что не файла NetOffice.dll. Смотрю папку Debug (нового проекта), там файла NetOffice нет. Пишу в код первого проекта строку "NetOffice.ExcelApi.Application SomeVar = new NetOffice.ExcelApi.Application();", сохраняю, компилирую второй проект и файл NetOffice.dll попадает..

Comment: @Serovkir: Ага, даже так? Странно, конечно, судя по всему, не распозналось как зависимость. А что со второй частью? Я бы всё же порекомендовал указать список нужных сборок вручную.

Comment: А как понять вручную? Все dll скачать и добавить их к проекту?

Comment: @Serovkir: Ну, э. Какой вы знаете способ получить объект типа Assembly? Не обязательно ж его получить из чужого списка, можно и самом создать по имени сборки. Вот и создайте список вручную.